# typescript infer string literal from ternary conditional

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-operator

This is a simplified example:

```
function doSomething(animal: 'bird' | 'fish'){ }

let flies=true;

const animal = flies ? 'bird' : 'fish'

doSomething(animal);
```

Typescropt infers type 'bird' | 'fish' in the assignation to animal from the ternary conditional. (if animal weren't const it would complain as it would infer type string not being assignable to 'bird' | 'fish')

But

```
const parms ={
    animal: flies ? 'bird' : 'fish'
}
doSomething(parms);  /* Argument of type '{ animal: string; }' is not    
                        assignable to parameter of type '{ animal: "bird" | "fish"; } */
```

Here it's infering string from the ternary conditional. Is there a way to keep things in this style (ie. not having to define a type and declaring the field animal as that type)

Comment: I guess the correct solution here is to define enum, but that is not what you are looking for, right?

Comment: @MartinAdámek yes, the real situation is more complex than this, not a big issue but I was wondering if there was something I was missing or could learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript only infers string literal types in certain situation. A property is unusually not one of those cases unless there are extra circumstances to hint a literal type for the property. (it has nothing to do with the ternary operator).

In Typescript 3.4 (unreleased at the time of writing, but already available as `typescript@next` in `npm`) you will be able to hint the compiler that you want object literals inferred as per [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) issue:

```
let flies=true;
//types as  { readonly animal: "bird" | "fish"; }
const parms ={
    animal: flies ? 'bird' : 'fish'
} as const
```

In 3.3 and below you could use a function to tell the compiler you want a literal type inferred:

```
let flies=true;
function withLiteralTypes<T extends Record<string, P>, P extends string | number | null | boolean | Record<string, P>> (o: T) {
    return o;
}
// types as { animal: "bird" | "fish"; }
const parms =withLiteralTypes({
    animal: flies ? 'bird' : 'fish',
})
```