# Union types fail as a generic type parameter

Tags: typescript

The following code looks correct to me, however TypeScript reports an error:

```js
type AorB = 'a' | 'b';

interface Container {
    aorb: AorB,
};

function example<T>(t: T): T {
    return t;
}

const aorb: AorB = example({ aorb: 'a' });
/*
Type '{ aorb: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AorB'.
  Type '{ aorb: string; }' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
*/
```

It looks as though the captured type is `{ aorb: string }` rather than `{ aorb: AorB }`.
What's the best way to prevent this?

See it in the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Atype%20AorB%20%3D%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Container%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20aorb%3A%20AorB%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20example%3CT%3E(t%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20t%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20aorb%3A%20AorB%20%3D%20example(%7B%20aorb%3A%20'a'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: This might also be useful as to how to get the compiler to infer string literal types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479507/typescript-infer-string-literal-from-ternary-conditional/54479694#54479694

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AorB` type is a string, but you passed an object to `example`. It should be either:

```
const aorb: AorB = example('a');
```

or

```
const container: Container = example({ aorb: 'a' as 'a' });
```